# Extending a polynomial to fit data: creating an arbitrary amount of functional parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I would like to fit a function to a given data set and if a condition isn't met, extend the function and repeat the procedure - similar to increasing the highest order of a Taylor series. My problem is that I don't know how to extend the function. This function is supposed to look like this

```
def func(x, a0,a1,a2,...)
    return (a0 * H0 + a1 * H1 + a2 * H2 + ...) (x)
```

H0(x), H1(x), H2(x),... are already known functions. I expect this method to use 20-1000 of the functions H0,H1,... so I have to find a way to not define each parameter a0, a1, a2,... by hand.

My idea was to define the function with a maximum amount of parameters and then manipulate it within a loop (reduce the number of parameters somehow and then increase them with each iteration)

```
# choose N: an arbitrary number of parameters
# create N-many functions H0, H1, ... HN-1 -> put them into an numpy array HArray

def func(x, parameters): # somehow reduce the number of parameters to N
    # convert parameters into numpy array -> parameterArray
    result = parameterArray * HArray (x) # (a * H0 + b * H1 + c * H2 + ...) (x)
    return result

# fit the function to a given dataset
```

As complete code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,num=10000) # xdata
y = np.sin(x) # ydata
error = 0.0001 # fit condition
K = 1000

for N in range(K):
    def func(x, parameters): # somehow reduce the number of parameters to N
        parameterArray = np.array([p for p in parameters])
        HArray = np.array([x**i for i in range(N)]) # a polynomial as example
        return parameterArray * HArray (x)

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

    stdDev = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    if stdDev < error: break
```

In order for the curve_fit to work, the function needs the appropriate number of parameters. I also had the idea of fixating the last K-N parameters while fitting, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is, if I get it right, a linear fit. There is, hence, no need for `curve_fit`. The most simple approach would be:

```py
import numpy as np

def h0( x ):
    return 1

def h1( x ):
    return x

def h2( x ):
    return x**2

def h3( x ):
    return x**3

def h4( x ):
    return np.sin( x )


def my_linear_fit( xdata, ydata, funclist ):
    ST = np.array( [ f( xdata ) for f in funclist ] )
    S = np.transpose( ST )
    A = np.dot( ST, S )
    AI = np.linalg.inv( A )
    K = np.dot( AI, ST )
    sol = np.dot( K, ydata )
    yth = np.dot( S, sol )
    diff = ydata - yth
    s2 = np.sum( diff**2 ) / ( len( diff ) - len( funclist ) )
    cov = s2 * np.dot( K, np.transpose( K ) )
    return sol, cov
    
"""
testing
"""

xl = np.linspace( -2, 8, 23 )
yl = np.fromiter( 
    ( 2.1 * h1( x ) + 0.21 * h3(x) + 1.56 *  h4(x) for x in xl),
    float
)

yn = yl + np.random.normal( size=len(xl), scale=0.2 )

opt, popt = my_linear_fit( xl, yn, ( h1, h3, h4 ) )

print( opt )
print( popt )
```

To avoid problems with matrix inversion etc there are ways to make this a bit more sophisticated using matrix decomposition and so on, but the main idea stays the same. If the input functions need additional parameters one might need to play with `lambda` function and/or extend the code accordingly.

**Edit 1**

Going to very high orders results in matrix inversion or floating point precision problems. We can get around this by using `mpmath`
Note, that `numpy` is not used anymore and some data handling needs to be done in a more manual fashion now.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import mpf
from mpmath import fabs
from mpmath import matrix
from mpmath import mp


def pol( x, n ):
    return x**n


def make_func_list( order ):
    out = list()
    for i in range( order + 1 ):
        out.append( lambda x, i=i: pol( x, i ) )
    return out


def my_linear_fit( xdata, ydata, funclist ):
    ymat = matrix( ydata )
    ST = matrix( [ [ f( x ) for x in xdata ] for f in funclist ] )
    S = ST.T
    A = ST* S 
    AI =  A**(-1)
    K = AI * ST
    sol =  K * ymat

    yth = S *  sol

    diff = ymat - yth
    s2l = [ x**2 for x in diff ]
    s2 = 0
    for x in s2l:
        s2 += x
    s2 /= ( len( ydata ) - len( funclist ) )
    cov = s2 * K *  K.T
    return sol, cov

"""
testing
"""
mp.prec = 50

xlth = [ mpf( -2 + (5 + 2) * i / 154 )for i in range( 155 ) ]
xl = [ mpf( -2 + (5 + 2) * i / 54 )for i in range( 55 ) ]
xmax = max( [ fabs( x ) for x in xl ] )
xls = [ x / xmax for x in xl ]
xlsth = [ x / xmax for x in xlth ]
yl = [
    2.1 * mp.sin( 3.83 * x ) for x in xl
]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 2 )

ax.plot( xl, yl, ls='', marker='o' )
bx.plot( xls, yl, ls='', marker='o' )

for order in[ 2, 4, 12, 18 ]:
    fl  = make_func_list( order )
    opt, popt = my_linear_fit( xls, yl, fl )
    print( opt.T )
    fit = [ [ o * f( x ) for x in xlsth ] for o,f in zip( opt, fl ) ]
    fitsum = fit[0]
    for line in fit[ 1::]:
        fitsum = [ x + y for x, y in zip( fitsum, line )]
    bx.plot( xlsth, fitsum)
plt.show()
```

**Edit 2**

Actually, numpy has a build in mechanism for this. I am not sure how it is done in detail as it eventually calls functions from a library, but I'd guess it uses SVD. QR decomposition is still be helpful to get the covariance matrix.

```py
from scipy.linalg import qr

def my_linear_fit( xdata, ydata, funclist ):
    ST = np.array( [ f( xdata ) for f in funclist ] )
    S = np.transpose( ST )
    q, r = qr( S )
    sol = np.linalg.lstsq( S, ydata )[0]
    yth = np.dot( S, sol )
    diff = ydata - yth
    s2 = np.sum( diff**2 ) / ( len( diff ) - len( funclist ) )
    cov =  np.linalg.inv( np.dot( np.transpose( r ), r ) ) * s2
    return sol, cov

"""
testing
"""

xl = np.linspace( -2, 8, 55 )
xmax = max( np.abs( xl ) )
xls = xl / xmax
yl = np.fromiter(
    ( 2.1 * np.sin( 2.83 * x ) for x in xl),
    float
)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 2 )

ax.plot( xl, yl, ls='', marker='o' )
bx.plot( xls, yl, ls='', marker='o' )

for order in[ 5, 10, 15, 20 ]:
    fl  = make_func_list( order )
    opt, popt = my_linear_fit( xls, yl, fl )
    fit = np.array( [ o * f( xls ) for o,f in zip( opt, fl ) ] )
    fit = np.sum( fit, axis=0 )
    fits = np.array( [ o/(xmax**n) * f( xl ) for n, o, f in zip( range(order + 1), opt, fl ) ] )
    fits = np.sum( fits, axis=0 )
    ax.plot( xl, fits)
    bx.plot( xls, fit)
plt.show()
```

**Edit 3**

This would be the solution using only QR decomposition. In my case it works easily up to order 20 (with re-scaling)

```py
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular

def my_linear_fit( xdata, ydata, funclist ):
    n = len( funclist )
    ST = np.array( [ f( xdata ) for f in funclist ] )
    S = np.transpose( ST )
    q, r = qr( S )
    rred = r[ : n ] ### making it square...skip the zeros
    yred = np.dot( np.transpose( q ), ydata )[ : n ]
    sol = solve_triangular( rred, yred )
    yth = np.dot( S, sol )
    diff = ydata - yth
    s2 = np.sum( diff**2 ) / ( len( diff ) - len( funclist ) )
    cov =  np.linalg.inv( np.dot( np.transpose( r ), r ) ) * s2
    return sol, cov
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I'm just trying to figure out how to solve the problem with the matrix inversion.

Comment: Here you have a post using `svd`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53591350/803359 You could also use QR decomposition.

Comment: There is one thing that I do not understand: I tried the example of H_i = x**i and i = 0,1,2,...N. I varied N, the highest order for the approximation, and the higher N gets, the better the approximation function is (used RMS), but then after a certain N is reached it starts getting worse. I expect the more polynomials are used, the better the approximation should become. Why is that so and how can I fix that?

Comment: Hi, there are several factors that could cause the issue. For very high polynomial orders, depending on your `x` values, you might get the `y` values varying over several orders of magnitude. This results in a badly conditioned matrix and solving it, will result in numerical errors. It might help if you define the higher orders with a small factor already. One can also think about working with logarithms. I guess it is clear that the number of polynomials must not exceed the number of points. Cheers

Comment: I tried the method my_linear_fit with H_i = x**i (i=0,1,2,..., N) on a couple of simple examples: y = x, sin(x) and the taylor series for sin(x) up to order 13. In all of those cases the method produces good results for small N. But when N > 9, the error starts growing larger. Even for an example as simple as y=x, it starts getting really bad, really soon.

Comment: Found out, that this is a problem due to floating-point error. Since I want to use higher orders of polynomials than just 10 and I don't know in advance how big the numbers will become in advance, I need another method. For the case of H_i = x**i I found a numpy method for this numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit, but I need a more general one. I'm trying to understand the code for this method, but for a beginner it's a bit too much code.

Comment: There is a rather simple solution to this: rescale your data to have it  as x in [-1,1] or something similar. The fit parameters can be scaled back easily, especially if you do not include offsets so x -> a * x. If you take x -> b * ( x - x0 ) it is a bit more cumbersome but no magic either.

Comment: But even then, floating point rounding errors will occur.  So you may want to use [`mpmath`](https://mpmath.org/). Technically I think a fit up to order 20 seem doubtful, at best.

Comment: I see. But, in case of using the scipy.curve_fit method, I can choose a polynomial of order 20 and it fits without any problem. Why does this work so well?

Comment: I guess that is a question of matrix inversion. `curve_fit` is a non-linear fit, so it only checks local numerical gradients.....I have a nice version with mpmath, though....let me put the Edit.

Comment: ....but as I mentioned before....this code has the most simple approach for solving a linear system, namely simple matrix inversion. There are more sophisticated methods. In this simple approach I have seen cases with negative errors due to floating point issues. So, might be worth looking into other methods ( see above ) Cheers

Comment: Note....numpy has a build in function for this...another edit.